# Creating a Windows Virtual PC image from a Physical machine

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

On Windows 7 (Home Premium), using **Windows Virtual PC**, how can you create an image of a physical machine running Windows XP?

I've found the "[Virtual Server 2005 Migration Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualserver/bb676674.aspx)", but this is of course for Virtual Server 2005, not Windows Virtual PC. I've also found [this link](http://cmoud.i.ph/blogs/cmoud/2007/03/19/how-to-migrate-physical-computer-to-microsoft-virtual-pc-machine/), but it is targeted to "Microsoft Virtual PC" (i.e. the previous version of Virtual PC).

Note: I am not interesting in using an alternative virtualization software (such as VirtualBox, VMWare, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the Sysinternals utility [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx). Should do what you're after if I understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

This step-by-step article describes how to create a Microsoft Virtual PC virtual hard disk that is an identical copy of a physical hard disk by using a backup disk image file:

**[How to create a Virtual PC hard disk image by using a backup disk image file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912826)**

if you're getting a BSOD because of the different hardware, just do a repair installation.